# put animated android tutorial for swipepage

Tags: android, fragment, swipe

hi i have an app it has some fragment and viewpager its some poem and when the user swipes to right it will go to the next poem however i want to inform the user that he should swipe the screen.

android itself does that in some cases it shows an animation that you can swipe and after the first time it wont show that somehow "tutorial" to the user how can i use those animations tutorial that android itself provide in my apps?
this is my main

```
public class Main  extends FragmentActivity {
    MyPageAdapter pageAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        List<Fragment> fragments = getFragments();


           pageAdapter=new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        ViewPager pager =

        (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

    }
    private List<Fragment> getFragments(){

        List<Fragment> fList = new ArrayList<Fragment>();


        for(int i=1;i<22;i++){

            fList.add(DetailsFragment.newInstance(i));
        }

        return fList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to Add a Toast Message when your app loads, in onCreate():

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Swipe Right to get more poems!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```